# How to deny Project Admins permission to manage user rights?

Tags: azure-devops

How to deny Project Administrators permission to manage user rights?
So that he keeps all the Admin rights in the Project, but can no longer add or delete users in the Project.

In the web portal, all rights of the Project Administrators group are grayed out. Despite the fact that I am Project Collection Admin.

I found a similar question: [Prevent project admin from adding new user to project and organization in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732448/prevent-project-admin-from-adding-new-user-to-project-and-organization-in-azure)
But that answer only indicates that you should then not make the user a member of the Project Administrators group, but not how to give the user all Project Admin rights except manage user rights.

---

*edit 13-04-2021*

According to [Hugh Lin - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11508192/hugh-lin-msft)'s answer you cannot take away the right to manage users from the Project Administrators group, you have to create a new group.
But, how can you give that new group the other rights of the Project Administrators (underlined on this picture)?
[image: Project Administrators groep description]

And you can see that the Project Administrators group is used in many places (at many [object-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#build-object-level) permissions), how does the new group get the same permissions in all those places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Administrators are granted [all project-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups), have the highest permission of the project.  You can't change the permission settings for the Project Administrators group. This is by design.

[image]

[image]

This is stated in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#change-the-permission-level-for-a-project-level-group).

So if you don't want a user in the Project Administrators to manage users right. You need to remove this user from the Project Administrators group. Add the user to a new project group and grant all permissions, set all permissions to `Allow`.

In the newly created custom group, we can only assign the permissions given in the list. Some permissions exclusive to the project administrator group cannot be granted.

Comment: Thanks.
So if we create a new group, say Custom Project Admins, and make the user a member of that, then that user can do everything that the default Project Administrators group can do except manage users, or are there more things that the user can no longer do then?
And I see that the Project Administrators group is used in many places, how does the new group get the same permissions in all those places?
See also the modification in my question.

Comment: In the newly created custom group, we can only assign the permissions [given in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Wqt.png).  Some permissions exclusive to the project administrator group cannot be granted.

Comment: Okay, clear. So it's not more finely tuned.  

My question stems from the desire (or requirement) that we don't want users from our Azure AD to be able to be added to our Azure DevOps projects without registered approval.  

As Azure DevOps is currently structured, the management of Projects is rather decentralized. And without users in the Project Administrators role, you're missing a whole lot of that decentralization.

Comment: But maybe we can use/misuse the Preview feature _"Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects"_ to ensure that a Project Administrator can no longer add **new** users, if he is also added in the `Project-Scoped Users` group.

Are there any **disadvantages** to such a configuration?

Comment: I tried to [turn off this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsZ9s.png), but users in Project Administrator can still add users, this option does not seem to work.

Comment: You need to turn **on** that feature, see [Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/limit-user-visibility-and-collaboration-to-specific-projects/). I tried it out with a Project Administrator user added to the `Project-Scoped Users` group. And he could no longer add new users to the project :-). But could still modify the permissions of the current users :-(.
And also got an annoying banner saying _"Your administrator has limited your access to organization-level data. [Learn more](https://aka.ms/azure-devops-hide-org-settings)"_.

Comment: Indeed, it can’t fully meet your needs. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.